# Gecko WebBrowser not getting HTML within frameset

Tags: vb.net, gecko

I have developed a win application in `VB.NET` and I am using `Gecko WebBrowser` to read html text from source page.
Now I want to read `HTML` within frame tag in source page.

In normal Visual Studio WeBBrowser you could do:

```
Dim document = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document
```

But in Gecko WebBrowser there is no `Window.Frames` property. What can i do to get HTML within frame or frameset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Gecko` web browser in `VB.NET` try this:

```
Dim document = GeckoBrowser.Window.Frames(0).Document
```